# VueJs 2 doesn't invoke Ajax request in the "ready" function

Tags: jquery, ajax, vuejs2

This is related to [Initializing Vue data with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413905/initializing-vue-data-with-ajax)

I am currently using Vue 2.2.4. I created a Vue element, and the ajax function inside "ready" block, just like the above example, but nothing is rendered. No console.log is printed indicating that those ajax request is not even invoked. Anybody knows what's going on? assume that I have to use the jQuery ajax lib for this task.

Below is my code:

```
var newJobsVue = new Vue({
    el: '#new-jobs',
    data: {
      jobs: []
    },
    methods: {
      ready: function () {
          var self = this;
          return $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch',
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: {
              'v': '2', 
              'format': 'json', 
              'publisher': <My_Key>,
              q: 'javascript',
              l: '94112',
              userip: 'localhost',
              useragent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2)',
              latlong: '1'
            }
          })
          .done(function(response){
            //render the jobs from the search_response
            console.log("response is>>>>>", response.results);
            //nope, this is not actually logged
            self.jobs = response.results;
          })
          .fail(function(error){
            console.log("error is>>>", error);
            // neither is this one logged
          });
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never call `ready`.  Try

```
var newJobsVue = new Vue({
    el: '#new-jobs',
    data: {
      jobs: []
    },
    methods: {
      ready: function () {
          // alot of code...
      }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.ready();
    }
  });
```

Comment: It might be good to note that `ready()` is actually a lifecycle hook, so you can use it the same way as `mounted()`. He might have just confused the methods and lifecycle hooks.

Comment: @woutr_be you mean in Vue 1?

Answer (score 0):

You can also initialize your data using `created` hooks or hooks that run later than `beforeCreate` hook : `beforeMount, mounted`. **In the created hook**, you will be **able to access methods, reactive data and events are active** while in `beforeCreate` hook you can't access your data and methods.

Brief : **use created hook** if you want to **initialize your data in the earliest time posible** or **use a hooks that run later than `beforeCreate hook` to initialize your data**

```
var newJobsVue = new Vue({
    el: '#new-jobs',
    data: {
      jobs: []
    },
    methods: {
      ready: function () {
          your ready function
      }
    },

    created(){ // can also be replace with beforeMount and Mounted
        this.ready();
    }
  });
```

Reference :

- [Understanding Vue.js Component Instancing - alligator.io](https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-instancing/)